# How do I change an images src attribute depending on two different environments?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page which contain a collection of images which all have a specific path prefixed to them, *img*.

```
<img src="img/foo.gif" >
<img src="img/bar.gif" >
<img src="img/baz.gif" >
```

I have a loop which goes through the collection of images:

```
container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
             imgSrc = /img\//gi,

for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
    var images = container_images[i];

    if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
        images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, 'new/path/here/');
    }
}
```

Now this works perfectly **locally** however when I run this on my company's QAF server, it appears the server is adding a dev path:

```
<img src="http://ryelxusecqcm1.rye.com:8080/us-home/tools/img/foo.gif">
```

Thus when my if block fires:

```
if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
    images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, 'new/path/here/');
}
```

I will get :

```
<img src="http://ryelxusecqcm1.rye.com:8080/us-home/tools/new/path/here/foo.gif">
```

Is there a way I test for both environments?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Oscar kindly added a solution involving `location.protocol` and `location.host` This is what I came up with:

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/',
           emailUrl = /img/gi,
           ewemailUrl = root + emailUrl;

    for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
            var images = container_images[i];

            if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
                images.src = images.src.replace(newemailUrl, '/new/path/here/');
            }
    }
```

But that doesn't work. In his answer he did away with the `.replace` method, but looks like he forgot a piece. Can anyone help me get it over the finish line?

```
if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
    images.src = images.src = location.protocol + '//' + location.host +  'new/path/here/');
}
```

Comment: What is the desired result? To have `new/path/here/foo.gif` without `http://rye...` in the `src` attribute?

Comment: Yes! I can already achieve this locally. It's just in DEV and I suppose this will happen in PROD.

Comment: You don't need `if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1)`. If pattern doesn't exist then nothing happens with the string (`.src`).

Comment: @Alex could you code it out/or explain a bit more? Not understanding what you mean.

Comment: `'abcd'.replace(/[0-9]/g,'')` doesn't change the string.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev THANKS! Whenyou have a moment could you please make a demo?

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
    images.src = images.src = location.protocol + '//' + location.host +  'new/path/here/');
}
```

Prepending  hostname and protocol to to your images folder variable  will make it machine agnostics.

Also, if you have some kind of config system in your application, add this value as a settable key in that config system.

Comment: Thanks for your help. DId you mean prepend?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz Yes, I mean prepend, just thinking fast, sorry. I'll update the asnwer

Comment: Thanks! I tried `imgSrc = root + /img\//gi;  if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) { images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, 'new/path/here/');}`. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz See if i made it better ;-)

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to include the `xxx.jpg` part. I think you might have overlooked that I was originally replacing some of the path. If you scroll to the right of your answer above  you'll see the `)` which was part of the original `.replace` method.